# cloudbees, groovy, jobs, folders: How to determine the job result, if the job is within a cloudbees folder?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, directory, cloudbees, jenkins-scriptler

**Problem**: I'm using a script to determine if a certain amount of jobs are in SUCCESS state.
It worked fine as long as I was not using cloudbees folder plugin. I could easily get the list of projects and get the project result. But after I moved the jobs to the cloudbee folder, the jobs and therefore the job results are no longer available!

**Q**: Does anybody now how to get the job results with groovy from jobs which are located in a Cloudbees folder?

Answer (score 18):

```java
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('foldername/jobname');
```

Comment: Finally found time to test... Works like a charme... It was so obviously easy, that I'm wondering why I did'nt found the solution myself... :-)
Many thanks...

Comment: You are welcome! Do not forget to “accept” the answer if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: @jesse-glick Is it possible to get all jobs in a cloudbees folder or all jobs in all cloudbees folders from the top of the tree?

Answer (score 4):

Folder plugin provides the `getItems()` method which can be used to get all immediate items (jobs/folders) under a folder.

```
folder.getItems()
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/vphad/Jenkins/blob/master/TraverseJenkins.groovy) to traverse across all the folders in Jenkins.

Displaying the code snippet below,

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*

import hudson.scm.*
import hudson.tasks.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.*


jen = Jenkins.instance

jen.getItems().each{
    if(it instanceof Folder){
        processFolder(it)
    }else{
        processJob(it)
    }
}

void processJob(Item job){

}

void processFolder(Item folder){
    folder.getItems().each{
        if(it instanceof Folder){
            processFolder(it)
        }else{
            processJob(it)
        }
    }
}
```