# How to get JOB_NAME when jenkins job inside the folder using groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have jenkins job `test_job` inside folder `Test` as `Jenkins->Test->test_job`

In my groovy script job is defined as below.

```
def JOB_NAME = manager.build.getEnvVars()["JOB_NAME"]->Test/test_job
def job = Hudson.instance.getJob(JOB_NAME)-> null
```

but `job` returns null. How do we get `job` or `job.fullDisplayName` with valid values?
by the way, `job` returns correct value if my job at root level like `Jenkins->test_job`

Comment: why do you need an instance of job? In most cases it is better to look for plugins or already defined pipeline steps before accessing internal methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked with below code.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(JOB_NAME);
```

Post https://stackoverflow.com/a/21728885/12062563 helped me.